# What happens to extra arguments in sh invocation?

Tags: sh

If I run `sh -c "prog arg1 arg2 arg3"` then prog is run with the arguments passed to it. That is straightforward. If I miss off the quotes, `sh -c prog arg1 arg2 arg3` then prog is run with no arguments. But what happens to the arguments? Does sh just silently ignore them, or do they serve some function? The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) is (in my opinion) a bit unclear

> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are  arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

As far as I can see, "arguments after the string" are not assigned to positional parameters.

Comment: if you don't use quotes, only the first word(in your case `prog`) is considered as the "string" that is written in the man page. the rest is considered as other parameters of `sh` command

Comment: Background: OpenDylan uses execve and a command starting "sh -c" to start an external process. This didn't seem to work as expected but it is now very clear after  John Kugelman's answer.

Comment: The documentation is a little misleading; `$0` isn't a positional parameter, but one of the shell special parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra arguments are indeed assigned to the positional parameters. `$1`, `$2`, etc., are available in the command being executed.

```
$ sh -c 'echo "0=$0; 1=$1; 2=$2"' foo bar baz
0=foo; 1=bar; 2=baz
```

If you wanted them to be passed *to `prog`*, you'd have to write something like:

```
sh -c 'prog "$1" "$2" "$3"' sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Or, more generically:

```
sh -c 'prog "$@"' sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

(Notice that I've prepended `sh` to the argument list to ensure `$0` is set to the name of the shell rather than `arg1`.)